# trying to convert extents of bounding box in object space to screen space

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

as in subject i want to convert 3d point in object space to screen space. I already lost some days to figure out this myself by reading some solution in internet but i still have wrong result. Here pic with the closest result i achieved:

[wrong rect](http://s7.postimg.org/xhq48xozf/wrong_rect.png)

"screen space" extents are represented by red lines, which are obviously wrong. Vertexes should be placed like there  (look at blue lines):

[correct](http://s28.postimg.org/87ufozbyl/correct_rect.png)

there is my func to convert object to screen:

```
public Vector2 WorldToScreen( Vector3 pos, int width, int height) {

        var pos4 = Vector4.Transform (new Vector4 (pos, 1), modelViewMatrix*projectionMatrix);

        var NDCSpace=pos4.Xyz/pos4.W;
        return new Vector2(NDCSpace.X*(width/2f),NDCSpace.Y*(height/2f));
    }
```

here are func for setup proj and modelView matrix for camera:

```
public void SetProjectionMatrix()
 {
    projectionMatrix  = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)(FieldOfView * Math.PI / 180.0), AspectRatio, ZNear, ZFar);
}

  public void SetModelviewMatrix()
 {
     var translationMatrix = Matrix4.CreateTranslation(-entityObject.position);
             var rotationMatrix = Matrix4.CreateFromQuaternion(ToQuaterion(entityObject.rotation));
        //modelViewMatrix = rotationMatrix*translationMatrix; orbit 
             modelViewMatrix = translationMatrix*rotationMatrix; //pan
}
```

NDCSpace seems to me that they return correct values (-1..1 when completely inside view frustum) so i think error is in rendering part with final matrix transformation. Here is my func for drawing screen space extents. For drawing debug info i use immediate mode. (dont worry, for meshses i use VBO)

```
int[] size=new int[4];
        GL.GetInteger (GetPName.Viewport,size);

   var   orthoProjMatrix=Matrix4.CreateOrthographic(size[2],size[3],Camera.main.ZNear,Camera.main.ZFar);
        var tmpMat = orthoProjMatrix;

        GL.MultMatrix (ref tmpMat);

        GL.PushMatrix ();

        GL.Color3(System.Drawing.Color.Red);

        DrawHelper.DrawRectangle (Camera.main.WorldToScreen(mesh.bounds.Min,size[2],size[3]),Camera.main.WorldToScreen(mesh.bounds.Max,size[2],size[3]));

        GL.PopMatrix ();
```

Last idea was to try to use billboard matrix but no success. I didnt tested this idea extensively though, not sure if this will work in this case.

anyone could help me?

EDIT:
here is DrawRectangle

```
public static void DrawRectangle(Vector3 pos1, Vector3 pos2){

        GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.LineLoop);
        GL.Vertex3(pos1.X, pos1.Y,pos1.Z);
        GL.Vertex3(pos1.X, pos2.Y,pos1.Z);
        GL.Vertex3(pos2.X, pos2.Y,pos2.Z);
        GL.Vertex3(pos2.X, pos1.Y,pos2.Z);
        GL.Vertex3(pos1.X, pos1.Y,pos1.Z);
        GL.End ();
    }
```

here model matrix, this is mesh model matrix

```
public void SetModelMatrix(){
        mesh.ModelMatrix=Matrix4.CreateScale(entityObject.scale)*Matrix4.CreateRotationX(entityObject.rotation.X) * Matrix4.CreateRotationY(entityObject.rotation.Y) * Matrix4.CreateRotationZ(entityObject.rotation.Z) *Matrix4.CreateTranslation(entityObject.position) ;
    }
```

rotation is in degrees

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your transform to NDC. It should be ProjMat * ModelView * PosVector. Is that what's happening? Also, don't you need to specify which matrix stack you push to, and wouldn't you also need a modelmatrix when drawing immediate mode? Those are the only nitpicky things I can come up with. Good luck.

Comment: I use Opentk which is opengl binding BUT! with one major difference in matrix transform - opentk use directx notation which mean projection matrix is applied as last. I tried model*ortho matrix in immediate mode this seems partially solved Y but Y have some error (screen Y doesnt match exactly world Y of extents) while X is still completely wrong. i will post screenshot later

Comment: What kind of model matrix did you use? Also, what does DrawHelper.DrawRectangle do? can you show the code?

Comment: Additional info already added chech edit section

Comment: As clarification, when drawing the rectangle, your model matrix should be the identity matrix. I'm not sure what the error is though, your code appears to be comparable to the way I used to do it.